# Why are constant electric fields considered when their energy is infinite?

Tags: electrostatics, energy, energy-conservation, singularities

Sometimes in some problems (that i am facing in high school physics related to electrostatics) like the problems of finding flux crossing through a cube where magnitude of electric field is some constant $K$ and in a particular direction.

**Why do we take the electric field to be constant everywhere?**

I mean that we all are familiar with the formula of energy stored in electric field to be

$$\int \frac12 \epsilon_0 E^2\, \text dv.$$

**That would make the energy stored in this field to be infinite**.

But still we are being taught these cases. I have seen other cases like this where the field is proportional to $x$ coordinate, etc.

Now is this a thought that everyone thinks before doing the question, or am I just the fool who keeps on checking about these things in almost all problems?

---

One thought is that why are we studying these cases is that the **electric field is constant for the patch we are observing** or there is only **slight variation in magnitude of electric field in that patch**

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that these are just teaching examples, or that these fields only exist in a finite space?

Comment: An example, based on the comment of BioPhysicist: assume that the cube in question is between two parallel charged plates.

Comment: "[A]m I just the fool who keeps on checking about these things in almost all problems?"  You're not a fool.  This is a good habit to cultivate, and it will serve you well as you proceed in physics.

Answer (score 4):

Of course constant electric fields are an approximation, which are valid only in very definite regions of space (e. g. inside a capacitor). For example, the case of the electric field of an infinite plane is valid either if one admits the existence of infinite planes or if one says that there is a very big (but finite) plane and that one is looking in places close enough to the plane to negelct "boundary effects". One can thus assume that the field there is constant but this is valid only *as long as one stays close enough* to the plane!

In then one wants to compute the total energy stored in the field using "your" integral, a more precise version of it would be

$$1/2\epsilon_0\left[ \int_{close\; to\; the\; plane} E^2_{const}\; dx + \int_{rest\; of\; space} E^2_{unknown} dx \right] $$

where we have split the integral in space in two parts: one close to the plane where we assume the fiels is constant and one in the rest of space where we do not know the field. You can however be sure that the total integral will not be infinite, as the one "close to the plane" is in a finite volume (and thus is finite) while the other one will not diverge as the field is not constant anymore, but will decrease as you go away from the source!

Another way to see this is that whatever realistic charge distribution you have (a very big plane, a very big sphere, a very big whatever), if you are *far away enough* it will still look to you like a point charge so that if the distance from the source $r$ is *big enough* the field decreases as $\sim 1/r^2$ (the electric field of a point charge) and the integral of the energy converges.

Again, we can write:

$$1/2\epsilon_0\left[ \int_{close\; to\; the\; plane} E^2_{const}\; dx + \int_{rest\; of\; space} E^2_{unknown} dx \right] \approx $$

$$1/2\epsilon_0\left[E^2_{const}V_0 +  \int_{rest\; of\; space} A/r^4 dr \right] <\infty $$
where $V_0<\infty$ is the volume in which the constant field approximation is valid and $A$ is just a constan to get rid of the details. The second integral is not infinite, and the total energy stays finite! (Of course there will be a transient between a constant $E$ and a $E\sim 1/r^2$ situation which I neglected here..!)

So, summing up, the "constant field" approximation is only valid in finite volume (unless you assume infinite charge distributions).

Comment: The field will go as $r^{-2}$ far from all sources, not $r^{-1}$.

Comment: whoops, mixed it up with the potential. Fixed.

Comment: Technically the field will go to zero *at least as fast* as $\propto r^{-2}$.  If the source has zero net charge, the fall-off will be even faster.  But the argument still holds in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Same reason why we say $g=9.8 m/s^2$. It's obviously not constant, but... is it an approximation? Yes. Is that approximation valid? It is... within a certain region

A constant electric field is a mathematical construct. You can study iut mathematically. Then, in physics, you have to know the scope of those calculations.

Comment: but we talk about this case(like my prof said that this is a good approximation only near the surface of earth). But we also study its variation with height but not in this case

Comment: Of course. Re-read the 2nd paragraph